# css modules in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am having some trouble with css modules in react I dont know how to use react modules in a dynamic way

````
import classnames from 'classnames'
import styles from './hover.module.css
///
///
const [flashElements,setFlashElements]=useState(elementList.map(element => {
        return element.classes.flash
    }))```

///
///
````

I want to be able to display the classes showing the value that corresponds to the element in state . is this even possible or should I approach the problem differently
I want to be to do some thing like the code below

```
return (
     <a classname={styles.HOVER ,styles.flashElements[i]}>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `import styles from './hover.module.css'` try using `import './hover.module.css'` in your component and you can directly use the class names from your CSS file.

Use `className`instead of `classname`in your `<a> tag`